# Android Studio Git not updating Remote

Tags: android-studio, github

I updated Android Studio to 2.2.2 and now my source files
are not being updated in the remote Git repository.However my .idea and .gradle folders are.
Why would this be?
How can I get the source files to be pushed as well?

I get this message at the bottom of Android Studio 
Push successful Pushed 1 commit to master/t
t being by branch but twhen I check on Github on the web there are no changes.

Comment: .idea and .gradle folders shouldn't be remotely tracked by VCS. If you don't see changes in your staged area, it's because they're skipped by .gitignore file. Why you want to push them?

Comment: I want to push my source java files because they are the source files I do not want to push .idea or .gradle.

Comment: Ok, are you using Android Studio plugin? issue is that you're not able to push java files or you don't see them in the staged area? if they're new maybe you're not tracking them. Try executing `git add .` from terminal

Comment: I click the vcs up arrow a dialog appears and I click commit and push

Comment: So how do you know your source files are not being updated in the remote Git repository?

Comment: I go to github on the web and they haven't changed for a month.

Comment: Can you see on github your last commit? look at the `log` tab in Android studio, check local and origin branch position according to your last commit and check committed files too

Comment: The log tab in android studio show the commit and so does Github but the source file is not updated.

Comment: If you select commit on Android Studio, do you see java files on the right?

Comment: There is no source files in there only the main app fileidea and workspace.xml

Comment: You've not committed java files. If you don't see them in `local changes` tab in Android Studio you have lost changes probably. Do you see changes in your local code?

Comment: To be honest I don't know -if I am looking at remote or local give up

Comment: Thanks for your help